# Game Mode: call StartPlay when second map is loaded

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

I've just started to learn Unreal Engine 4.26.2 and C++.

I have two maps: one used only to show the main menu, and another one to play the game (Pong clone).

On my GameMode, which inherits from Game Mode Base, I have implemented method Start Play. My problem is that method must be called when the player enters into the game (when the second map is shown), but that method is called when the  game start.

Is there any method to call when the second map is loaded? I have thought to call a custom Game Mode method from second map level blueprint.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using two maps then you can use the [Open Level](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Game/OpenLevel_byName/) node which allows you to call a new level by name.

In your maps and modes, choose your menu level for the game start map.